# javascript compare .text() with .val() goes false everytime

Tags: jquery, text

I have something like this:

```
var nn = $("#nickname" + i +"_").text();
var search_nn = $("#search_nickname").val();
```

One is a span box (search_nn) and nn is a textbox.
They have the same value.
I use a if statement to compare, but it`s always false...

I tried to use String() function but still doesn't work.

Comment: For the span, you must use `.html()`

Comment: Show your HTML markup

Comment: .val() is ~only for inputs

Comment: Assuming by textbox you mean a input with type text, it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/eG5PE/

Comment: var i =58; 
 nn = $("#nickname" + i +"_").text();
 search_nn = $("#search_nickname").val();
 
 document.getElementById("wtf").innerHTML= "Span:"+ nn + "Input:" + search_nn ;
  
 
 if (nn == search_nn){
  $("#r59_").hide();
  }else{
  $("#r58_").hide();
 }    Span:AlphAInvok Input:AlphAInvok

Comment: for my span I think it inserts a newline at the end for no reasons...

Comment: Are you sure the values are the same? I suspect there's some excess whitespace in one of those values that means the values are not actually the same.

Comment: Solved. Newline was the problem, i used substr() to check and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

This may clear your query...

[http://www.api.jquery.com/text/](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

.text() will give you text which may affected with css and .val() will return pure value